# What does Binding Path=Name mean in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, collectionviewsource, groupstyle

I am newbie and am confused of some syntax of ListBox.GroupStyle. The code:

```
    <Window x:Class="testCollectionViewSource.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Window.Resources>
            <CollectionViewSource x:Key="CVS" Source="{Binding Path=Cs}">
                <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                    <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="B" />
                </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            </CollectionViewSource>
        </Window.Resources>
        <Grid>
            <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource CVS}}">

                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock   Text="{Binding S}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>

                <ListBox.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ListBox.GroupStyle>

            </ListBox>

        </Grid>
    </Window>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Cs = new ObservableCollection<C>();
        Cs.Add(new C(true, "1"));
        Cs.Add(new C(false, "2"));
        Cs.Add(new C(true, "3"));
        Cs.Add(new C(false, "4"));
        DataContext = this;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<C> Cs { get; set; }
}

public class C
{
    public C(bool b, string s)
    {
        B = b;
        S = s;
    }
    public bool B { get; set; }
    public string S { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is why only when {Binding **Name**} does the header displays "True" or "False", and why {Binding **B**} not work? What does "Name" mean, since the **Class C does not have such property**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you inspect the application using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), you'll realize the `DataContext` of your `TextBlock` and it's ancestors up to the [`GroupItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.groupitem(v=vs.110).aspx) is an object of type `MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal`, which contains a `Name` property:

[image]

This is why `{Binding Name}` works in there, while `{Binding B}` does not.

Answer (score 2):

[Name](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a Property of [CollectionViewGroup Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewGroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is the default `DataContext` for collections grouped by `CollectionView` based on `GroupDescriptions`.

Answer (score 2):

When you use grouping `DataContext` of each group will be set to an instance of [`CollectionViewGroup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which, apart from `Items`, stores some information about the group itself. [`Name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewgroup.name%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will represent the value under which items have been grouped. So in your case when you do:

```
<PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="B" />
```

it means that you create different groups for different values of `B` and because it's of a `Boolean` type it means that there are only 2 groups possible. One for `B == true` and second for `B == false` hence text in your header